# Importing Georaster into BlenderGIS causes blender to not respond

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, blendergis

I am trying to load a geotiff of the UK into blender, when I try with smaller files it seems to work.
I am thinking that maybe blender cannot handle the size of this geotiff, is there anyway to stop it from crashing (whilst retaining information)?

[image]
[image]

Comment: What is your goal to import GeoTiff into Blender? Maybe there is another path. Also, try contacting the Blender GIS developer, I did it a while ago when I had a problem and he answered me, turned out it was a bug in Blender GIS.

Comment: Hi @MarcosSaito , I'm trying to import a GeoTiff into blender and drape a shape file over it. This is so that I can export it as a model into unity. I've managed to open up my shape file and GeoTiff in QGIS and viewed a 3d model in qgis2threejs but I'm unsure of how to get this into unity.

Comment: So you want a terrain model with texture into Unity? Do you have a picture or example of what is the final result you want? (just a off-topic comment: I've used Unity some years ago and now I'm using Unreal. It seems to me that Unreal handles terrains in general in a better way.)

Comment: @MarcosSaito So I have a geotiff for the UK terrain, and I wanted to drape road networks (with traffic data in the form of a shape file). I have rendered in 3D on QGIS2threejs, I'll edit an image into the original post so you can see. I'm hoping to get this terrain model (+roads) into Unity for a project i'm working on.

Comment: Also! Thanks for the heads up about unreal, I'll look into that over the weekend :).

Comment: What about:
1. Cropping both the Geotiff and the SHP with a square from a third SHP (so that both have a coincident area).
2. After that, convert both to PNG. 
3. Then, open the PNG (from the tiff) in the game engine as a elevation model (apply it to a plane mesh for example), and the PNG (from the SHP) as texture (to the same plane mesh or terrain object). 
4. Since both cover the same area and have the same size, it will fit perfectly in the game engine, but without correct scale or position. 
I think this approach works both in Unity and Unreal

Comment: If you want to try Unreal, take a look at this links: https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/Engine/Landscape/Custom
https://forums.unrealengine.com/development-discussion/content-creation/13917-real-world-map. Be aware that Unreal is a complex tool, it will take sometime to get used to it and understand what is going on.

Comment: @MarcosSaito Thanks! I'll go with that first idea, I think if I get the shape file PNG to the same resolution it should lay on top pretty well. And the rest I should be able to sort out within unity.

Comment: Give feedback here if it works (don't know if you should post as an answer and accept, because it actually doesn't solve the original question...). One of the issues I had with Unity that made me move to Unreal was that Unity had the need for a very specific type of PNG (RAW 16 bit, don't remember now), while on Unreal I just got it right in the first attempt with many types of PNGs.

Comment: @MarcosSaito Yeah, It worked, but the main point of me trying to input the shapefile was to read the data embedded. I will keep researching, but thanks for your help! :)